# Permissions for Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms, editor-user-permissions

I have 2 requirements:

1. How can we make sure that Content Author should not be able to edit a form that is saved as template. They should only be able to create forms from a template, but not edit the template itself.
2. How can we block the export form data to excel option for all user.

How can I achieve these two goals?

Updated 06/01/2021:

If the Export Data dialog is disabled , then also it did not work for admin role. How do I restrict for admin role as well.

Also any suggestions on point 1?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this activity by following below steps:

Logged in CMS as admin, then switch to core db
Now from LaunchPad go to Security Editor then select the user(to whom wanted to restrict)
goto below path    `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Dialogs/ExportDataDialogWindow`
and restrict read and write access as per below attached screenshot

[image]

Restriction for editing on existing form, look bit tricky
Basically for this if switch back to master db, and from security editor restrict all access, then user will not able do any activity on existing form but also will not able to view.
And if we give read access on Forms node then editing also getting enabled looks like existing Forms issue.

Comment: Export Data dialog disabled , but it did not work for admin role. How do i restrict for admin role as well.

Comment: If you are talking about checkbox "Administrator" for a user account, this user will bypass permission.